# Refresh one row in cxGrid

Tags: delphi, grid, row, refresh

I have seen there is a problem refreshing only current row if the data are changed in another form (and DataSet too) or even if the data are changed on server side (in trigger or from another user).
So i find solution that partially work with DevExpress's cxGrid and have following issue.

```
  frm:=TfrmEdb01.Create(Self);    // create edit-form
  try
    frm.LoadData(0);              // do the insert in TAdQuery
    frm.ShowModal;                // Show edit form

    // after closing an Edit-Form, make a new record in cxGrid
    row:=tv01.dataController.InsertRecord(tv01.Controller.FocusedRecordIndex);

    // for each column in grid...
    for col:=0 to tv01.DataController.ItemCount-1 do
    begin
      // ...get its FieldName
      sFld:=tv01.DataController.GetItemFieldName(col);
      // and if this field exist in edit-form's Query
      if frm.q01.FindField(sFld)<>nil then
      //then assign this value to the newly created row in the grid.
        tv01.DataController.Values[row,col]:=frm.q01.FieldByName(sFld).Value;
    end;
  finally
    frm.Free;
  end;
```

And realy, when I step out from the edit-form there is a New row created in the cxGrid. Problem is in that:
- if is double-clicked (to open edit-form again) then the previous record is opened. It seems to me the Data acctualy did not updated in Query object, only in GridView... maybe I should use values from Grid instead of Query object. 
- if select another record (scroll them up and down), and then want to select again this new record, then it can not be focused at all. Only if I reload whole dataSet, then this new record can be selected same as any other.

Cheers!

p.s. To clearify a problem, I will provide whole test-project. There is also SQL script to create a table in the database, and AnyDac connection must be set to Your database. 
There is also an image thate will/should ilustrate a problem.

[image: Issue ilustration]

Comment: Have you tried (temporarily) adding a TDBNavigator to the same form as your cxGrid? That should show you what state the dataset is in, which may differ from what you think it is.

Comment: There is a navigator on the bottom of the grid, but nothing is changed after this for-loop is executed. But, the biggest problem is why this new recor can not be selected at all.

Comment: Well, it looks to me like you may be going about this the wrong way - instead of trying to copy values into the grid's datacontroller, I would create a create a new record in the datacontroller's dataset, and leave it to the grid to do what it's supposed to do, i.e. display things rather than copy data.  Trying to manipulate data **in** a cxGrid is almost always the wrong thing to do - manipulate the dataset's data instead.

Comment: I may not and can not do the insert on the live DataSet (TAdQuery). Maybe if use TClientDataSet, then can manualy add a records at runtime. But this is not a case.

Comment: Sounds to me like you are fighting with the state-machine inside the TDataset-descendant you're using.  That's what happens when you try to manipulate data using db-aware components like the cxGrid DBTableView.

Comment: Btw, "I may not and can not do the insert on the live DataSet":  Then try switching the AdoQuery to (disconnected) "briefcase mode" and deal with whether to insert the new row into the back-end table later in the process..

Comment: Uh, it is not so easy to do at this time. However, have solve first issue, and it remain another a problem why this new record can not be selected (focused).

Comment: obviously the dataset stores a local copy of the db data to dataset by dataset. use the same dataset in the form (inject in in the form constructor) as in the outside data control or invalidate the outside one state to refresh its state.

Comment: Despite our exchamge of comments, there is insufficient information in your q for readers to be able to understand exactly what you are doing or exactly what the problem is.  I am voting to close the q until you provide an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You have call post to save the changes to the underlying dataset. Do it just before `finally`.

```
tv01.DataController.Post();
```

See the help for TcxCustomDataController.Post for more details.